# PHP: Как в свойствах одного класса использовать переменную $ другого?

Tags: php, массивы, классы, объекты, переменные

Пишу авторизацию в api. Сделал два класса. Информацию, генерируемую в одном, нужно использовать в другом.

```
class Auth {
public $url = "https://auth.xxxxxxxx.ru/auth/login/";
public $credentials = [
    'user_name' => 'xxxxx',
    'user_pass' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'product_code' => 'xxxxxxx'
    ];

    public function moveaway (

здесь получаю ответ сервера и кладу его в переменную $sidfinal
)

class Takecid {
    public $url1 = "https://auth.xxxxxxxx/billing/id/";
    public $second = [
        'sid' => **$sidfinal**,
        'ogrn' => '1071650001796'
];

public function cid ()
{
    $injson = json_encode($this->second);
    $nextstep = curl_init($this->url1);
    curl_setopt($nexts...
```

В моем варианте скрипт не срабатывает, выдает вот какую ошибку:
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

Как же передать данные из одного класса в другой, а именно: в его свойства, в массив нужных значений, которые потом потребуется переделать в JSON...

Попробовал такой вариант:

```
class Takecid extends Auth {
    public $url1 = "https://ллллллллл/billing/id/";

    public function cid ()
    {
        $a = parent::__construct();
        var_dump($a);
        $second = [
            'sid' => $a,
            'ogrn' => '1071650001796'
        ];
        $injson = json_encode($this->second);
        $nextstep = curl_init($this->url1);
        curl_setopt($nextstep, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($nextstep, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $injson);
        curl_setopt($nextstep, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($nextstep, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//        curl_setopt($getting, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        $output2 = curl_exec($nextstep);
        curl_close($nextstep);
        echo $output2;
//    echo $output2;
    }
}

$c = new Takecid();
$c->cid();
```

Comment: через конструктор?

Comment: Я набредал на этот инструмент(https://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/konstruktor-php.html), но не представляю, как им в данном случае воспользоваться. Мне же надо в новом классе использовать совершенно новые данные...

Comment: при чем здесь какие-то левые поделки? мы о классах говорим. [слышал когда-нибудь о конструкторах](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.decon.php)?

Comment: Не вижу полноценной картины, где и как используются классы... Но насколько я помню эту ошибку идёт обращение к необъявленной/неинициализированной переменной объекта

Comment: $sidfinal успешно выводится.. первым классом, проверял, а ошибка связана со строчкой, на которой находится это:'sid' => **$sidfinal**, - свойства второго класса..

Comment: @Ипатьев, внимательно прочитал информацию по ссылке, пока не понимаю, чем может быть полезно с моей проблемой..

Comment: и даже слова "код всегда выполняется при создании класса" не натолкнули ни на какие мысли?

Comment: Это не говоря о том, что "делать два класса" вообще не имея понятия о "написанном по ссылке" - это очень странный подход. может быть стоит все-таки сначала почитать, что такое классы, а потом уже "делать два"?

Comment: выше "код при создании *экземпляра* класса" конечно же

Comment: @Ипатьев, добавил в вопрос попытку на основе __construct и дочернего класса.. Но все равно, как ни странно, не отрабатывает.. Пишет вот что: {"request":{"code":14,"message":"wrong parameters"},"data":null}

Comment: не надо никаких екстенд. просто в конструктор Takecid передать экземпляр Auth и там присвоить свойству

Comment: вообще не очень понятно, что делает класс Takecid . достает переменную из джейсона?

Comment: class Takecid {
    public $url1 = "https://jjjjjj/billing/id/";

    public function __construct ()
    {
        $h = new Auth();
        var_dump($h);
        $l = $h->moveaway();
        var_dump($l);
        $second = [
            'sid' => $sidfinal,
            'ogrn' => '1071650001796'
        ];

Comment: var_dump($l); - NULL дает... в чем-то я ошибся..

Comment: В api все так устроено, что тот, кто авторизуется сначала получает один ответ json, затем, он должен уже его передать в новом запросе, чтобы окончательно войти..

Comment: для этого второй класс создал..

Comment: Зачем вам второй класс? Либо сделайте 2 метода в классе Auth и поочередно их вызывайте, либо просто в одном методе выполняйте последовательно 2 curl запроса к серверу api.

Comment: Сделал, как Вы посоветовали, объединил две функции в один классы, так точно рациональнее..